# Integrating cordova plugin paypal with ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, paypal

I'm trying to use the paypal-cordova-plugin to integrate paiement on my mobile app. But the instructions I am following are asking for sandbox id and production id but I have no idea where to find them in paypal. Can someone help me on this ?

This is the place where they are asked

```js
angular.module('app')
  .constant("shopSettings", (function () {
    return {

      payPalSandboxId: "Aar8HZzvc5NztVWodTBpOiOod9wWrBDrJUjyvRr4WsxcCD28xYig7oecfYsqxQUDu5QHptPpSALirxZD",

      payPalProductionId : "production id here",

      payPalEnv: "PayPalEnvironmentSandbo", // for testing production for production

      payPalShopName : "SenPass",

      payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL : "url to policy",

      payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL : "url to user agreement"


    }
  })());
```

This is the link I'm following : http://ionicandroidlearning.blogspot.fr/2015/11/ionic-paypal-integration.html

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what is your problem .. you don't know where to get the PayPal keys from portal?..or how to set these keys in your ionic app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First you need to create an account on [paypal developers](https://developer.paypal.com/).
2. Then inside the dashboard create a new application (**REST API apps**).[image: dashboard]
3. When you create the new app, Paypal will generate a **sandbox account** and a **client id** for you.
4. Add the code (example):

```js
var configuration=function () {
 var configOptions = {
  merchantName: "Some name you have specified", 
  merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: "http://yourserver/privacypolicy",
  merchantUserAgreementURL: "http://yourserver/agreement",
  languageOrLocale: "en_US"
 };
     // for more options see paypal-mobile-js-helper.js
     var _config = new PayPalConfiguration( configOptions );
     return _config;
}
var onPrepareRender = function(){
 $log.info(" ======= onPrepareRender ==========");    
} 

var onPayPalMobileInit = function(){
 var payPalConfig =  configuration();    
 PayPalMobile.prepareToRender("PayPalEnvironmentSandbox", payPalConfig, onPrepareRender);
 deferred.resolve( payPalConfig );
}

var clientIDs = { 
 "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": '', //leave it blank
 "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": 'your sandbox id'
};

PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, onPayPalMobileInit);
```

Comment: Ok I manage to have the sandbox id by generating it and going back to the profile of the account. I guess that is what I have to put inside my **payPalSandboxId** variable. What about the **payPalEnv** or should I leave it blank ?

Comment: I have not use that **payPalEnv**, in the code snippet I pasted is all that you need. See how I pass the information to **PayPalEnvironmentSandbox**

Comment: Ok so Im going to implement it the same way to see how it is going to be.

Comment: @Hosar Can you help me out with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393955/add-paypal-payment-method-ionic/44394436?noredirect=1#comment75790178_44394436

Comment: Can you please help... Where to put the SECRET associated with the Client ID in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

to retrive PayPal Sandobx keys try to go here:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/
```

click on your generated account for testing (in the table) and then on Profile ...it open a modal with some tabs .. choose the `API Credential tab`

Hope it can help you

Comment: Ok thanks I've seen the informations you are talking about. Are they really the ones needed in the screenshot I made in my post ?

Comment: @federico scamuzzi can you help me out with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393955/add-paypal-payment-method-ionic/44394436?noredirect=1#comment75790178_44394436