# Add PayPal payment method Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, paypal

I'm trying to implement PayPal payment method on my APP made with Ionic 2/3, I allready installed

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/paypal
```

but now how can I create the event button, I mean I need when I press a button it calls the PayPal API giving them the product and price I guess and then make the payment.

I've read the [Paypal Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/) but when it puts **Usage** I don't know where I have to put this code.

Anyone can guide me how to implement it? Or at least a guideance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a chance to test this myself, but you could have a button that invokes `initiatePaypal()` which would look like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { Paypal, PaypalPayments } from 'ionic-native';

import {PayPal, PayPalPayment} from 'ionic-native';
//import {PayPal} from 'ionic-native';


@Injectable()
export class Payments {

paymentdata : any;
paymentdetails: any;

constructor() {

}

initiatePaypal(){
PayPal.init({
        "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
        "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31ACxTIGBF1mQyNN7DjU1eCzpAZer8"
        })
    .then(onSuccess => {
        console.log("init success")
    })
    .catch(onError => {
        console.log("init failed", Error)
    });
}


initiatePayment(){

    this.paymentdata = new PayPalPayment("10.00","SGD", "MMS tickets", "MMS sale");

    PayPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(this.paymentdata)
    .then(onSuccess => {
         console.log('OnSuccess Render: ' + JSON.stringify(onSuccess));
         alert('OnSuccess Render: ' + JSON.stringify(onSuccess));
       })
    .catch(onError=> {
       console.log('onError Render: ' + JSON.stringify(onError));
       alert('onError Render: ' + JSON.stringify(onError));
         });
}



}
```

If all else fails, try to follow along this vanilla js [example usage of the plugin](https://github.com/romk1n/MyCordovaShop/blob/master/www/js/index.js). Taken from [`MyCordovaShop`](https://github.com/romk1n/MyCordovaShop).

Comment: Thanks for answering, this should be on different class? I mean I have a Home class which have products, then from that screen I press BUY item so I call an onClick from home.ts passing per parameter price and product name, would be ok?

Comment: I'm loking the link you have put on answer and it's a Js code, would be a problem if I put that code on a .ts?

Comment: No, there will be no problem. Typescript is a superset of Javascript, so think of it as JS++. Any Javascript code you put in a .ts file compiles and runs just fine (as long as it is correct js code).

Comment: Ok, I'll test the code and I'll let u know what's going on

Comment: how do I get the EnviromentSanbox? I think I have my client_id but I don't find the enviromentSandbox id

Comment: From the [Paypal Developers website](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/) I get this: When testing your Adaptive API calls in the Sandbox, use the following static `AppID` value for the Sandbox: `APP-80W284485P519543T`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145995/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-maninak).

Comment: What about the Secret Key where to use it in the code?